# Remove first few entries from dynamoDB list datatype

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

High level requirements:

- There could be millions of users
- Any user could favorite another user
- A user's location tracking data needs to be stored. A max of 100 most recent data points have to be stored.

I'm thinking of using Dynamo DB to achieve it, by storing the data in following format (The motivation to use NOSQL is retrieval would be fast, since in one get I'll get the entire data):

```
{
    "userID" : 2323423,
    "favs" :    [
            userIDA,
            userIDB,
            ...
    ],
    "lt" :  [
            {"timestamp1" : "coordinate1"},
            {"timestamp2" : "coordinate2"},
            ...
        ]
}
```

userID is the primary key.

The query requirements are

1. Addition of deletion of favorites should be possible.
2. A bunch of new timestamp <=> GPS location pairs could come, which I need to feed into that user's "lt" data. As there's a limit of 100 LT data points, I need to remove the oldest ones too.

I'm pretty sure that (1) is straight forward using the add/remove APIs on List data type. 
How do I solve query (2)? It would be best if the UPDATE query itself somehow could iterate over all the objects and delete ones which are old. I've read that the indexes in list as understood by Dynamo DB is in integer format, so can we leverage that somehow? Are the elements in a list always indexed from 0 to N? If that is so, I can remove the appropriate number of elements from the beginning of the array. Is there any way to do it?

I'm open to using a different data schema, but please let me know the entire reasoning and how this could be solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) The attribute "favs" should be defined as SET data type in order to use DELETE feature. Please note that you can't use DELETE on LIST data type.

The Delete operator can be used only on SET.

> DELETE - Deletes an element from a set.
>
> If a set of values is specified, then those values are subtracted from
>   the old set. For example, if the attribute value was the set [a,b,c]
>   and the DELETE action specifies [a,c], then the final attribute value
>   is [b]. Specifying an empty set is an error.
>
> The DELETE action only supports set data types. In addition, DELETE
>   can only be used on top-level attributes, not nested attributes.

2) To delete the occurrence (i.e. Object) from LIST data type, you should know the index. The update expression could be something like below:-

UpdateExpression : "REMOVE lt[0]"             - Remove one element

UpdateExpression : "REMOVE lt[0] lt[1]"       - Remove elements 0 and 1

Yes, the index starts from 0 to N for the LIST data type.

3) Conditionally removing the item - Yes, you can include the conditions in ConditionExpression. However, REMOVE requires index for the list item. Otherwise, it would delete the entire list (i.e. not the specific index from the list).

Also, when you would like to refer the MAP object inside list, you need the index of list.

**Example:**
To REMOVE the media.id=3, the conditional and update expressions should be as mentioned below:-

Please note that index is used in both conditional and update expressions.

**JavaScript syntax to remove "media.id" = 3:-**

```
var params = {
        TableName : "Product",
        Key : {
            "product" : "IPhone 7+"
        },
        UpdateExpression : "REMOVE media[2]",   
        ConditionExpression: "media[2].id = :idvalue",      
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {":idvalue" : "3",
        },
        ReturnValues : "UPDATED_NEW"
    };
```

**Data:-**

```
"media": {
            "L": [{
                "M": {
                    "url": {
                        "S": "http://www.apple.com/iphone-6-plus/a.jpg"
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "S": "image"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "S": "1"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "M": {
                    "url": {
                        "S": "http://www.apple.com/iphone-6-plus/b.jpg"
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "S": "image"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "S": "2"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "M": {
                    "url": {
                        "S": "http://www.apple.com/iphone-6-plus/overvie
                        w.mp4 "
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "S": "video"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "S": "3"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @notionquest. Another query, is it possible to delete old entries from the "lt" list if each of the entries inside it were Map with Key value pair of timestamp and coordinates?

{
  "timestamp" : 23423432434,
  "coord" : "2.34435, 0.3342343"
}

So, by scanning the table, deletion of those List entries inside "lt" where timestamp is older than some value?

Comment: it definitely helps. Can you please let me know if its possible to add elements to a list without a conditional expression, and delete stale entries inside that using conditional expression list in one go? I fear not, just wanted to confirm. I don't want to end up writing a cron which does a scan and removes the entries which are stale (wouldn't that be too much). I'm okay with keeping 100 data points or so for Location Tracking. Hope you could help.

Comment: just to add to my previous comment, I can run a query to append another coordinate entry to my location tracking "lt" list. Is there a way through which allows I can remove all the entries in a list matching the conditional expression? Its okay if I have to run this query separately. My motivation is to remove stale entries of the "lt" list whose timestamp is stale (more than 2 days old) or something like that.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible for your first comment (add elements to a list without a conditional expression, and delete stale entries inside that using conditional expression list in one go).

Comment: Okay, how about my last query, can I remove all the entries in a list matching the conditional expression?

Comment: Yes, you can delete the whole list based on some condition expression.

Comment: Thanks NotionQuest, can you please give me an example where a list may have data points like these:

{ "timestamp" : 23423432434, "coord" : "2.34435, 0.3342343" }

and I want to remove list entries whose timestamp is less than say some X?